# Celery periodic_task running multiple times in parallel

Tags: python, celery

I have some very simple periodic code using Celery's threading; it simply prints "Pre" and "Post" and sleep in between. It is adapted from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095940/running-unique-tasks-with-celery) and [this linked website](http://ask.github.com/celery/cookbook/tasks.html)

```
from celery.task import task
from celery.task import periodic_task
from django.core.cache import cache
from time import sleep
import main
import cutout_score
from threading import Lock

import socket
from datetime import timedelta
from celery.decorators import task, periodic_task

def single_instance_task(timeout):
  def task_exc(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        lock_id = "celery-single-instance-" + func.__name__
        acquire_lock = lambda: cache.add(lock_id, "true", timeout)
        release_lock = lambda: cache.delete(lock_id)
        if acquire_lock():
            try:
                func()
            finally:
                release_lock()
    return wrapper
  return task_exc

LOCK_EXPIRE = 60 * 5 # Lock expires in 5 minutes
@periodic_task(run_every = timedelta(seconds=2))
def test():
    lock_id = "lock"

    # cache.add fails if if the key already exists
    acquire_lock = lambda: cache.add(lock_id, "true", LOCK_EXPIRE)
    # memcache delete is very slow, but we have to use it to take
    # advantage of using add() for atomic locking
    release_lock = lambda: cache.delete(lock_id)

    if acquire_lock():
        try:
            print 'pre'
            sleep(20)
            print 'post'
        finally:
            release_lock()
        return
    print 'already in use...'
```

This code *never* prints `'already in use...'`; the same phenomenon occurs when I use the `@single_instance_task` decorator.

Do you know what's wrong?

**Edit: I've simplified the question so that it doesn't write to memory (using a global or the django cache); I still never see `'already in use...'`**

---

**Edit: When I add the following code to my Django settings.py file (by changing the code from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/ everything works as hoped, *but only when I use port 11211* (oddly enough, my server is on port 8000)**

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': [
            '127.0.0.1:11211'
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you running celeryd? I'm not familiar with a threaded option.

If it's running multi-process then there are no "global" variables that are shared memory between workers.

If you want a counter shared between all workers, then I'd suggest you use `cache.incr`.

E.g.:

```
In [1]: from django.core.cache import cache

In [2]: cache.set('counter',0)

In [3]: cache.incr('counter')
Out[3]: 1

In [4]: cache.incr('counter')
Out[4]: 2
```

---

**Update**

What happens if you force your tasks to overlap by sleeping, e.g.:

```
print "Task on %r started" % (self,)
sleep(20)
print "Task on %r stopped" % (self,)
```

If you don't get "already in use..." from running this more frequently then 20 seconds then you know that the cache isn't behaving as expected.

---

**Another Update**

Have you set up a cache backend in your django settings? E.g. memcached

If not you may be using the [Dummy Cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#dummy-caching-for-development), *which doesn't actually do any caching, just implements the interface*... which is sounding like a convincing cause of your problem.

Comment: +1 That sounds like it's related to my problem. I tried using the cache, but still see erratic values of `counter`. Also, I see that multiple workers enter the `test` function. I'm running celeryd with django: `python manage.py celeryd -v 2 -B -s celery -E -l INFO`

Comment: Even when I simplify so that the `test` function just prints "hello", it runs on different workers and prints much too frequently (even when I have the `@single_instance_task` decorator defined).

Comment: I've simplified the code (above) so that it only prints (as you suggested). It still never prints `'already in use...'`; somehow the cache isn't successfully locking.

Comment: Which cache backend are you using? I'm using this recipe successfully with memcached.

Comment: Ah-- I do `from django.core.cache import cache`; that's the one from ask.github.com/celery/cookbook/tasks.html. Also, it's important to allow celery concurrency >1. With concurrency = 1, it will never produce an error, but will never print 'already in use...'