# How do I write a custom decorator that correctly passes arguments to a celery task?

Tags: python, decorator, django-celery, python-decorators, djcelery

## Background and question

I'm using Django 1.5.1 and django-celery 3.0.17.  I want to write a custom decorator to ensure that only one instance of the function runs at a time, similar to [this](http://ask.github.io/celery/cookbook/tasks.html) but without all the repeated try/finally.

**How can I write a decorator so that Celery methods like `apply` and `delay` can be called with arguments?**

[Others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095940/running-unique-tasks-with-celery) have created such decorators with apparent success.  What am I missing?

## Implementations

I've tried writing the decorator both a function and as a class, but with either implementation, when attempting to decorate a function with both my decorator and `@celery.task`, the arguments are not passed to the decorated function, resulting in the error message:

`TypeError: foo() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`, where `foo` is the name of the decorated function.

### Functional implementation

```
# util.py
from functools import wraps
from django.core.cache import get_cache


cache = get_cache('filesystem')


def cache_lock(lock_id, timeout=cache.get('TIMEOUT', 720)):
    def _decorator(func):
        try:
            timeout_secs = timeout.total_seconds()
        except AttributeError:
            # Timeout is None (forever) or number of seconds.
            timeout_secs = timeout

        acquire_lock = lambda: cache.add(lock_id, 'true', timeout_secs) if timeout_secs else cache.add(lock_id, 'true')
        release_lock = lambda: cache.delete(lock_id)

        @wraps(func)
        def _apply_lock(*args, **kwargs):
            if acquire_lock():
                try:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                finally:
                    release_lock()
            else:
                return False

        return _apply_lock
    return _decorator
```

### Class-based implementation

```
# util.py
from functools import wraps
from django.core.cache import get_cache


cache = get_cache('filesystem')


class cache_lock(object):
    def __init__(self, lock_id, timeout=cache.get('TIMEOUT', 720)):
        self.lock_id = lock_id
        self.timeout = timeout

    def __call__(self, func):
        try:
            timeout_secs = self.timeout.total_seconds()
        except AttributeError:
            # Timeout is None (forever) or number of seconds.
            timeout_secs = self.timeout

        acquire_lock = lambda: cache.add(self.lock_id, 'true', timeout_secs) if timeout_secs else cache.add(self.lock_id, 'true')
        release_lock = lambda: cache.delete(self.lock_id)

        @wraps(func)
        def _apply_lock(*args, **kwargs):
            if acquire_lock():
                try:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                finally:
                    release_lock()
            else:
                return False

        return _apply_lock
```

### Test case

For both implementations, the first test method succeeds and the second fails.

```
# tests.py
from datetime import timedelta
from celery import task  # using celery.task.task does not help
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.utils import override_settings
from .util import cache_lock


class UtilTests(TestCase):
    def test_cache_lock_without_celery(self):
        @cache_lock('recursive', timedelta(seconds=1))
        def call_count(i):
            self.assertFalse(call_count(i + 1))
            return i + 1

        self.assertEqual(call_count(0), 1)  # succeeds

    celery_settings = {
        'CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER': True,
        'CELERY_EAGER_PROPAGATES_EXCEPTIONS': True,
        'DEBUG': True,
    }

    @override_settings(**celery_settings)
    def test_cache_lock_with_celery(self):
        @task(name='test_cache_lock_with_celery')
        @cache_lock('recursive', timedelta(seconds=600))
        def call_count(i):
            self.assertFalse(call_count.apply(i + 1).result)
            return i + 1

        self.assertEqual(call_count.apply(0).result, 1)  # fails!
```