# How to prevent the same task to be executed by celery?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-1.8

I'm implementing a cache server that uses a celery task to update the cache in background. There is only one task that I call it with different arguments (cache keys).

Since after connecting this server to my main production server it will receive tens of requests per second for the same cache key I want to make sure there are never more than one of the update tasks with the same cache key inside celery queue (working as a queue and a set at the same time).

I thought of using a redis set to make sure of that before running the task but I'm looking for a better way.

Comment: Is your requirement really "only one task with the same cache key inside celery QUEUE" or is it "only one task with the same cache key running (updating cache) concurrently"?

Comment: @MuhammadTahir only one task with the same cache key inside celery QUEUE

Comment: See if this works for you http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time. This will work as it is for the second case that I mentioned but it can be modified for your version (the first I mentioned) too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running "unique" tasks with celery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095940/running-unique-tasks-with-celery)

Comment: @funky-future Possibly yes. I will try to find the code I was writing at the time to check if there is any difference in requirements for both questions. Though I remember I solved my problem using this https://github.com/cameronmaske/celery-once .

Answer (score 3):

There is only one way, implement your own lock mechanism.
The official doc has a [nice example page.](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time).
The only limit is your imagination.

Hope this helps.