# Priority when acquiring lock with Redis and Python

Tags: python, redis

I wish a task not to be ran at same time by many users. So I used this code:

```
REDIS_CLIENT = redis.Redis()
lock = REDIS_CLIENT.lock("task_key", timeout=60)
have_lock = lock.acquire(blocking=True, blocking_timeout=60)
```

With 2 users, it works well. But with more than 2 users :

1. User 1 acquires lock for the task
2. User 1 runs task
3. User 2 tries acquiring lock for the task but it is already acquired so he waits
4. User 3 tries acquiring lock for the task but it is already acquired so he waits
5. User 1 task ends
6. User 3 acquires lock for the task
7. User 3 runs task
8. User 2 get angry because User 3 stole his place

At step 6, User 2 or User 3 can acquire lock randomly. But I would like to be sure User 2 acquires it first.

How to set a priority ?

PS : I use Redis to run "unique" tasks with celery : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19499540/5077962

Answer (score 0):

> How to set a priority ?

That's not a thing.

The issue is known as "lock fairness". If your redis client doesn't implement fair locks then your only option is to handroll it e.g. [based on the fair semaphore recipe](https://redis.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/chapter-6-application-components-in-redis/6-3-counting-semaphores/6-3-2-fair-semaphores/).

Comment: On the link you gave me, it says we want "to prevent clients on systems with slower
system clocks [to steal] the semaphore from clients on systems with faster clocks". I think that's not my point because all my requests are done on the same machine. Then, clock should be the same.

Comment: Anyway, if it does solve my problem, would you advice a python redis client which implements lock fairnesss please ?